# How does React useState hook work with mutable objects

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Let's say my component has a piece of state that is a set of selected IDs. Javascript has a `Set` type, so I try this:

```
let [selectedIDs, setSelectedIDs] = useState(new Set());
```

The Javascript `Set` is itself mutable, so I'm confused.

```
function toggleSelectedID(id) {
    let set = selectedIDs;
    if (set.has(id)) { set.delete(id) }
    else { set.add(id) }
    // ???
    setSelectedIDs(set);
}
```

If the `Set` objects where immutable, I would create a new `Set` with the added or removed element, and pass that new `Set` to `setSelectedIDs`, changing the state at that point.

But with the mutable `Set`, what would happen if we returned at the `???` line? Would React be in a bad state, because I "reached into" its state and mutated it without officially telling it about it with `setSelectedIDs`?

Comment: The last line would clearly not update the React state (at least I'm pretty sure), and react "doesn't care" that you don't change the state, it waits for you to do so than it Reacts and rerenders.

Comment: Oops, I should rewrite that part of the question. I meant that if I had an immutable set, and *made a new one* and then passed it to `setSelectedIDs`, then that would be the point where the state was updated.

Comment: This is pretty clear in the docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly React only updates from changes to state or props. You can mutate what's in the state but will need to re-set it to guarantee an up to date ui

Comment: Okay, that part makes sense - that React won't update unless I call `setState`, or the hook equivalent. I guess I've been doing a lot of functional programming lately, with immutable data, so I was worried that React could be hanging on to that state object and doing something with it, not expecting it to get mutated out from under it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, `setSelectedIDs` not updating application `state`.

That's because you set the same reference, you should make a copy:

```
setSelectedIDs(new Set(set));
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/n3lrk5l1yl?fontsize=14) example.

---

> What would happen if we returned at the *???* line

Nothing would happen, you just changed a variable in your function, you can do it as many times you like.

When you want your React-App to notice the change, you should then call a function the updates the state (`setSelectedIDs()`) and your app will be rerendered.

Refer to [Using State Correctly](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly)

Comment: I guess if the set were really big, and I didn't want to recreate it, I can trigger the rerender by having the state be a little wrapper object, which gets recreated. `set.add(x); setSelectedIDs({items: set})`

Comment: const [assetDetails, setAssetDetails] = useState({}), my initial state is like this and then i am calling setAssetDetails({name : 'Himamnshu', age : 28}). BUt this is not working.

Comment: @Mansuu.... please just ask a question, you need to add some context and examples