# Why in one function state is updated immidietly and in other isn't

Tags: reactjs

so I know that `setState()` is asonchrynus but I don't understand when It is. I always run into this problem when mapping lists in react. Specifically when I delete list element. 
This function updates state instantly and rerenders array.map() function:

```
const handleHistoryDel = (index) => {
    setHistory(history.filter((_, i) => i !== index));
  };
```

And this one updates state but doesn't rerender:

```
const handleHistoryDel = (index) => {
    let temp=history;
    temp.splice(index,1)
    setHistory(temp);
  };
```

What is the difference? Should second function use some kind of callback? If so how would you implement one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because temp has the same memory address reference, when you run `array.filter` you get a new array, allocated in another space.

when you write `let temp = history;` you get the same reference, React will compare the previous state with the current one, if they have the same reference, it will not re-render.

try yourself:

```
const handleHistoryDel = (index) => {
  let temp = [...history];
  temp.splice(index,1)
  setHistory(temp);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe pass a function inside the setState like this,

```
setHistory(prev =>  // Do some changes here and return it  //   )
setHistory(prev => [...prev])
```

Also refer to this answer that explains about immutablity

[How does React useState hook work with mutable objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55820536/11566161)

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new array without reference to the state's array.
And then `mutate` the newly created array.

```
const handleHistoryDel = (index) => {
    let temp=[...history];
    temp.splice(index,1)
    setHistory(temp);
  };
```